# Spaceless is not working for removing whole html data spaces

Tags: javascript, html, symfony, twig

what i need

- i need to remove space between html elements.

twig code

```
    {% spaceless %}

            <head>

            {% block title %}
            <title>times</title>
            <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <meta name="description" content="" />
            <meta name="keywords" content="" />
            {% endblock %}  
            <meta property="fb:admins" content="10timesevents" />
            <meta property="fb:app_id" content="432858816746099" />

            {% block css %}

            <noscript>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://im.gifbt.com/css/skel-noscript.css" />

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://im.gifbt.com/css/style9.css" type="text/css" >

            {% if DeviceDetcet() =='computer' %}
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://im.gifbt.com/css/style9-desktop.css" type="text/css  />

            {% elseif DeviceDetcet() =='tablet' %}

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://im.gifbt.com/css/style9-1000px.css" type="text/css  />

            {% elseif DeviceDetcet() =='phone' %}
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://im.gifbt.com/css/style9-mobile.css" type="text/css  />

            {%endif%}
            </noscript> 
            {% endblock %}

            {% block scripts %}
            <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />     
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


            {#      <script src="http://im.gifbt.com/js/jquery.poptrox-2.2.js"></script>#}
            <script src="http://im.gifbt.com/js/skel.min.js"></script>




            {% if DeviceDetcet()=='phone'%}
            <script src="http://im.gifbt.com/js/skelnew-panels.min.js"></script>
            {%endif%}
            <script src="http://im.gifbt.com/js/common.10.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>


            {% endblock %}



            <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="http://im.gifbt.com/js/html5shiv.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://im.gifbt.com/css/ie8.css" /><![endif]-->

            </head>
            {% block body_tag %}
            <body>
            {% if  'android' in UserAgent() or 'Android' in UserAgent() %}
            <div style="position:fixed; width:100%; z-index:9; right:0; left:0; bottom:0;">
            <div class="row flush">
            <div style="height:60px; background:#fb6d02; padding:14px 7px 7px 7px!important; border-bottom:1px solid #e16000; border-top:1px solid #e16000">
            <img src="http://im.gifbt.com/images/android100.png"style="float:left; width:30px; padding:0 5px 0 0" />
            <p style=" font-size:.9em; line-height:1.1em; margin:0; ">
            <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tentimes&referrer=utm_source%3Dsite%26utm_medium%3Dbottom-banner" target="_blank" style="float:right; font-size:1.1em; line-height:1.6em; text-decoration:none; color:#fff; background:#333335; padding:.3em .7em; margin-top:1px;">Download Now</a>
            <b class="bld" style="float:left; padding:7px 0 0 0; color:#fff">Stay updated with 10times App</b>
            </p>
            </div>
            </div> 
            </div>

            {% endif %}
            <span id="evtname"></span>

            <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
            <noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-MMVJS3" 
            height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
            <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
            new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
            '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
            })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-MMVJS3');</script>
            <!-- End Google Tag Manager --> 
            {% endblock %}
            <!-- Header Wrapper -->
            {% block homepage_head %}
            {#Fixed navbar#}
            <div class="navbar navbar-static navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="margin:0; min-height:38px; offsetheight:38px!important">
            <div class="not-mobile" style="background:#fff">
            <div class="new_header">
            <div class="headerdiv">
            <div class="l">
            <ul class="navigation">
            <li><a href="{{ DomainDetect()}}/tradeshows">Trade Shows</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ DomainDetect()}}/conferences">Conferences</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ DomainDetect()}}/top100">Top 100</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ DomainDetect()}}/venues">Venues</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="c">
            <a href="http://10times.com" class="newlogo" ></a>
            </div>
            <div class="r">
            <div class="user-nav">
            <div id="header-login-dd-link">&nbsp;
            <div class="user-dropdown dis-non">
            <ul class="udr">

            <li><a class="manage udbr" href="http://{{-login_url}}">Manage Event</a></li>
            <li><a class="contact udbr" onclick="feed_back();">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a class="signin udbr" onclick = "signin();">Sign In</a></li>
            <li><a class='dashboard udbr' href='http://{{-login_url}}/dashboard'>My Dashboard</a></li>


            </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="screen-block" style="display: none;"></div>

            <a class="advt" href="{{ DomainDetect()}}/services">Advertise</a>
            <a href="{{ DomainDetect()}}/addevent" class="adevnt">Add Event</a>
            <div class="searchdiv">
            <span style="margin-top:10px" class="srhbx 4u" id="srh"><input type="button" value=" " class="srhbtn" onclick="checkHeaderSearch($(this));" id="explore-button" style="float:right" /><div id="search-box-area" class="p-relative search-box-area zind"><input type="text" name="" autocomplete="off" id ="explore-keywords" placeholder="search" 
            class="srhtxt homesearch" style="width:75%" required /><div id="explore-keywords-dropdown" autocorrect="off" ><div id="keywords-dd" class="kkdd"><ul id="keywords-by" style="margin:0;"></ul></div></div></div></span>
            </div> 
            </div>
            {#<div class="searchdiv">
            <form action="{{ DomainDetect()}}/search" method="get" id="srh">
            <div class="srhbx" id="search-box-area ">
            <input type="text" class="srhtxt homesearch" autocomplete="off" id ="explore-keywords" placeholder="Search" name="q" {% if DeviceDetcet()=='computer'%} style="width:75%" {%endif%}  required="">
            <input type="submit" value="&nbsp;" class="srhbtn" required="" >
            <div id="explore-keywords-dropdown"  autocorrect="off" >
            <div id="keywords-dd" class="kkdd">
            <ul id="keywords-by" style="margin:0;"></ul>
            </div></div>
            </div>
            </form>
            </div>  
            </div>#}
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="only-mobile">
            <div class="new_header">
            <div id="hide-header" class="headerdiv">
            <div class="l">


            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle toggle-left" data-toggle="sidebar" data-target=".sidebar-left" style="margin:4px 0 0 5px; border:0; padding:8px">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            </div>
            <div class="c">
            <a href="/" class="newlogo"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="r">
            <div class="mobile_menu">
            <a onclick="change();" class="srhbtn">&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div id="search-field" class="headerdiv dis-non" style="display: none;">
            <form method="get" action="http://10times.com/search" id="srh" class="mr">
            <div class="ll">

            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle toggle-left" data-toggle="sidebar" data-target=".sidebar-left" style="margin:4px 0 0 5px; border:0; padding:8px">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            </div>
            <div id="search-field" class="cc">
            <input type="hidden" name="cx" value="partner-pub-8525015516580200:vtujn0s4zis">
            <input type="hidden" name="cof" value="FORid:10">
            <input type="hidden" name="ie" value="ISO-8859-1">
            <input type="text" name="q"  id ="q"    placeholder="Search..."    class="srhtxt1" required />

            </div>
            <div class="rr">
            <input type="submit" value="&nbsp;" class="srhbtn1">
            </div>
            </form>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>

            </div>{#endo of new main col-md-12#}
            <div class="col-xs-7  col-md-3 sidebar sidebar-left sidebar-animate" style="background:#212628; padding:0; top:39px; position:fixed!important">


            <div id="sidebar-wrapper" class="only-mobile">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav" style="margin:0; padding:0;">
            <li class="only-mobile"><a href="{{ DomainDetect()}}" class="hm">Home</a></li>
            <li class="only-mobile"><a href="{{ DomainDetect()}}/tradeshows" class="ts">Trade Shows</a></li>
            <li class="only-mobile"><a href="{{ DomainDetect()}}/conferences" class="con">Conferences</a></li>
            <li class="only-mobile"><a href="{{ DomainDetect()}}/top100" class="tp">Top 100</a></li>
            <li class="only-mobile"><a href="{{ DomainDetect()}}/venues" class="vn">Venues</a></li>
            <li class="only-mobile"><a href="http://{{-login_url}}/addevent" class="ae">Add Event</a></li>
            <li class="only-mobile"><a href="{{ DomainDetect()}}/services" class="ad">Advertise</a></li>
            <li class="only-mobile"><a href="http://login.10times.com" class="mng">Manage Event</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>

            </div>

            </div>{#endo of row#}   

            </div>
            {% block heightfromhead %}
            <div style="height:51px" class="not-mobile">&nbsp;</div>
            <div style="height:40px" class="only-mobile">&nbsp;</div>
            {% endblock %}


            <!-- header end -->

            {% endblock %}
            {# {% block search_head %}body goes here!{% endblock %}         #}
            {% block body %}body goes here!{% endblock %}

            <!-- PAGE END -->

            <script type="text/javascript">
            function feed_back(){modal.open({content:'<div class="12u skel-cell-mainContent"><div class="box panel pd"><image src="/img/lineloading.gif"></div></div>'});$.get("/feedback",function(e){modal.open({content:e})})}
            </script>


            <script async src="http://im.gifbt.com/js/suggestive_search_2.js"></script>

            {% block bottom_script %} 
            <script async src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>

            {% endblock %}
            {#          <script type="text/javascript">#}
            {# $(document).ready(function(){#}
            {#  $("#searchpanel").removeClass('dis-non');   #}
            {# });#}
            {# </script>#}
            </div>


            {% if  'android' in UserAgent() or 'Android' in UserAgent() %}
            <script>
            $( document ).ready(function() {
            {% if cookie('get','10tphpopup') == '0'%}
            {{-cookie('get','10tphpopup')}}
            {{-cookie('set','10tphpopup',1,3600*24*365)}}
            //$("div").first().addClass('dis-non');
            var height=$( window ).height();
            //height=height-50;
            height=height+"px";


            {%endif%}
            });
            </script>

            {%endif%}
            {% if  'iPhone' in UserAgent() or 'iphone' in UserAgent() %}
            <script>
            $( document ).ready(function() {
            {% if cookie('get','10tphpopup') == '0'%}
            {{-cookie('get','10tphpopup')}}
            {{-cookie('set','10tphpopup',1,3600*24*365)}}
            //$("div").first().addClass('dis-non');
            var height=$( window ).height();
            //height=height-50;
            height=height+"px";



            //modal.open({content:'<div class="12u skel-cell-mainContent"><div class="box panel pd"><image src="/img/lineloading.gif"></div></div>'});$.get("{{ DomainDetect()}}/android?type=iphone",function(e){modal.open({content:e})})
            {%endif%}
            });

            </script>

            {%endif%}

            {% block bottom_script2 %} 


            {%endblock%}
            {% block bottom_script3 %} 

            {#<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ DomainDetect()}}/headersearch.css" />#}


            {%endblock%}
            {% if  'android' in UserAgent() or 'Android' in UserAgent() %}
            <script type="text/javascript">
            if(sessionStorage.getItem("count1")=='NaN')
            {
            sessionStorage.setItem("count1", 0);
            counters = 0;
            }
            if(sessionStorage.getItem("count1") == null)
            {
            sessionStorage.setItem("count1", 0);
            counters = 0;
            }
            else
            {
            counters= parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("count1"));
            //alert(sessionStorage.getItem("count1"));
            }
            if (page_count == 4)
            {
            dataLayer.push({'event':'mobilePromo-android'});
            }

            </script>

            {% endif %}
            {%if 'iPhone' in UserAgent() or 'iphone' in UserAgent() %}

            <script type="text/javascript">

            if(sessionStorage.getItem("count2")=='NaN')
            {
            sessionStorage.setItem("count2", 0);
            counters = 0;
            }
            if(sessionStorage.getItem("count2") == null)
            {
            sessionStorage.setItem("count2", 0);
            counters = 0;
            }
            else
            {
            counters= parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("count2"));
            //alert(sessionStorage.getItem("count2"));
            }
            if (page_count == 4)
            {
            dataLayer.push({'event':'mobilePromo-iphone'});
            }

            </script>


            {% endif %} 
            </body>


            </html>

            {% endspaceless %}
```

snapshot

[image]

- while using spaceless spaces between html element are not removed.
- i need to remove the spaces between html elements.
- i  have found use trim in twig but where to used in code.
- any suggestion are most welcome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Remove spaces in twig](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27958340/how-to-remove-spaces-in-twig)

Comment: question has been asked related removing spaces here ques is about removing spaces b/w html

Answer (score 0):

This always worked for me.

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    {% spaceless %}
        HTML and anything else code goes here where spaces are removed
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: but ist not ignore  &nbsp; and & bull element in html

Comment: can you tell me in my code how to trim whitespaces in my code is it possible in twig or through javascript

Comment: You need to read [this documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html) because by the look of yours, it needs to be refactored from scratch to use template inheritance. My answer above inherits `base.html.twig` so see what it looks like first then modify your code.

Comment: you could see in snapshot after being using spaceless problem still  there in html

Comment: finally i got solution this not possible at all

Comment: Yes it's not possible because Symfony removes spaces using a simple regular expression like `s/>[ \t\r\n]+</></`. Better solution would be not to use non-breaking spaces (`&nbsp;`) and instead use CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Spaces you're actually showing in your screenshot are between attributes, not tags.

That's why they are not removed.

If you look at Twig's source code, <kbd>lib/Twig/Node/Spaceless.php</kbd>, you can see the regular expression used:

```
public function compile(Twig_Compiler $compiler)
{
    $compiler
        ->addDebugInfo($this)
        ->write("ob_start();\n")
        ->subcompile($this->getNode('body'))
        ->write("echo trim(preg_replace('/>\s+</', '><', ob_get_clean()));\n")
    ;
}
```

As you can see, only spaces between html tags are removed.

Check [this fiddle](http://twigfiddle.com/tsj5bw), and especially the compiled template:

```
echo trim(preg_replace('/>\s+</', '><', ob_get_clean()));
```